# Custom Header in UICollectionView with Interface Builder without Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I'm trying to add a custom view to the header section of my `UICollectionView`. I have the xib file interface builder but I don't use storyboard. I have checked the Section Header in Interface Builder but doesn't appear any UICollectionReusableView, what can I do?

Answer (score 12):

The easiest solution is to do is programatically (and keep your HeaderReusableView in another XIB file):

```
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ItemHeaderView" bundle:nil]
          forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                 withReuseIdentifier:kItemSectionHeaderViewID];
```

Then:

```
- (CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                   layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return CGSizeMake(60.0f, 30.0f);// width is ignored
}
```

And of course:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
           viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind
                                 atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *productId = nil; ///

    ItemHeaderView *view = nil;

    view = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind
                                       withReuseIdentifier:kItemSectionHeaderViewID
                                              forIndexPath:indexPath];

    view.titleLabel.text = productId;

    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    return view;
}
```

Comment: I was using xib. you solution worked for me. Initially I was trying resister NIB `[self.selectionCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FlootThumbnailCollectionReusableView" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];`

 than I changed to

`[self.selectionCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FlootThumbnailCollectionReusableView" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView"]`